# Why this cmd regedit add command does not work?

Tags: cmd, regedit

Whats wrong with this cmd command:

```
REG ADD 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\SoftwareProtectionPlatform\Activation' /v Manual /t REG_DWORD /d 00000001 /f
```

Comment: You don't have permission. Only Admins do.

Comment: i executed this as admin

Comment: Use `"` not `'`.

Answer (score 0):

Replace **`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE`** with **`HKLM`**

Answer (score 0):

Did you check this path:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\software\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\SoftwareProtectionPlatform\Activation
```

Because Windows redirects `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software` to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\WOW6432Node`